# How to pass a local variable to lambda function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, c++14, stdvector

I have an integer `153`, and I need to determine whether or not he is equal to the sum of pow(*digit*, *digits*). so `153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153` returns `true`.

I chose to find the number of digits using a basic loop, then pushing all the integers into a vector so I could use the `std::for_each` function to iterate and use `pow()` on each of the elements.

The problem I am facing is the changing of each element. I don't want to resort to a *`for`-loop* yet, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it via the `for_each`.

Errors are commented in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

bool narcissistic(int value)
{
    int k{};
    std::vector <int> sum{};
    while (value > 0) {
        k++;
        sum.push_back(value % 10);
        value /= 10;
    }
    std::for_each(sum.begin(), sum.end(), [](int& n) {pow(n, k); }); // error: 'k' is not captured
                                                              // (warning) note: the lambd has no capture-default
    if (std::accumulate(sum.begin(), sum.end(), 0) == value) return true;
    return false;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << narcissistic(153) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) The error message gave you the key word "capture" -- look for that word in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the lambda function to capture k

- by value (the lambda function gets a copy) by using `[k](int &n) { pow(n, k); }`
- by reference by using `[&k](int &n) { pow(n, k); }`.

Read more about lambda captures at https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures

That being said, I wouldn't use a `std::vector` to solve your problem. You can directly use `unsigned int k = std::floor(std::log10(n)) + 1;` to get the number of digits in a number, and just accumulate the sum in your while loop. Make sure to check for n > 0 at the beginning though.

Answer (score 2):

> but I can't seem to figure out how to do it via the for_each.

You have a couple of problems there

- In the `while-loop` you are changing the original passed `value` here

  ```
  value /= 10;
  ```

  Therefore, latter you can not compare with it at the line.

  ```
  if(std::accumulate(sum.begin(),sum.end(),0) == value)
  ```

  You should preserve the original `value` for the latter comparison.
- Secondly, you need to sum the `pow(n, k)` up not the `sum` vector as
  it only contains the individual digits of the passed `value`.

  ```
  double sum{};   // since, std::pow returns the floating points 
  std::for_each(powVec.begin(), powVec.end(), [k, &sum](int n) { sum += std::pow(n, k); });
  //                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -> sum the powers of digits
  //                                                    ^^^^^^ -> no need of taking reference here
  //                                           ^^^^^^^^^ -> capture `k` by value, `sum` by reference
  ```
- Thirdly, the `std::accumulate(sum.begin(),sum.end(),0) == value` is
  wrong as `value` would have been already `0` at this time and the
  `std::accumulate` returns the sum of the individual digits(which is
  not what you wanted)

That means, change the program to: **([See online live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ggvD1nd4cbWzwbcw))**

```
bool narcissistic(const int value)
//                ^^^^ --> cons because, passed value can only read
{
    int k{};
    std::vector<int> powVec{}; // named as a vector of power of digits in the `value`
    int value_copy{ value };   // copy of original value
    while (value_copy > 0) {
        k++;
        powVec.push_back(value_copy % 10);
        value_copy /= 10;      // work with the copy of value
    }
    double sum{};  // since, std::pow returns the floating points
    std::for_each(powVec.begin(), powVec.end(),
        [k, &sum](int n) { sum += std::pow(n, k); });
    //   ^^^^^^^^-->capture `k` by value `sum` by reference
    // if (std::accumulate(sum.begin(), sum.end(), 0) == value) return true; // not required
    return static_cast<int>(sum) == value;
}
```

---

You can read more about the lambdas here:

- [Lambda
  expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)
- [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)